# Finding parents by matching on children FKs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with two tables, `Playlists` and `PlaylistItems`. PlaylistItems have a FK back to their Playlist. The tables look like:

```
PlaylistItems: Id (PK) | Title | PlaylistId (FK)
Playlists: Id (PK) | Title
```

I've got a couple of queries which find me PlaylistItems by title:

```
Select * from PlaylistItems where Title LIKE '%Geographer - Kites%'
Select * from PlaylistItems where Title LIKE '%Sam Kang%'
```

Each of these queries yields many results, but I believe that there should be only a minimal number of Playlists which contain both results. That is, I'm looking for all Playlists which contain both `'%Geographer - Kites%'` and `'%Sam Kang%'` as children.

I'm considering doing a `JOIN` on each of my Select statements, then performing a `COUNT` on the PlaylistId and return results which have a `COUNT > 1`. However, I think that solution will also show playlists which contains 2x `'%Geographer - Kites%'` and 0x `'%Sam Kang%'`.

Is there a more clever way to achieve this?

Comment: so you want to get the Playlists having both the conditions.? And then what is the count about?

Comment: Yes. I want to find all Playlists which have at least 1 match for each select statement. The count was just to see if there was at least 1 match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean, will this work, or can we work from here?

```
SELECT  * FROM Playlists WHERE ID IN(
SELECT PlaylistId FROM PlaylistItems where Title LIKE '%Geographer - Kites%'
INTERSECT
SELECT PlaylistId FROM PlaylistItems where Title LIKE '%Sam Kang%')
```

Comment: Oh wow. That was easier than I thought, I'm sorry. Yeah, that's exactly what I needed, just didn't think to use INTERSECT like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allergic to subqueries, you can try something like

```
select distinct PlaylistId from PlaylistItems where 
    Title LIKE '%Geographer - Kites%' and
    PlaylistId in (select distinct PlaylistId from PlaylistItems where Title LIKE '%Sam Kang%')
```

I don't have access to SQL Server, so I haven't been able to verify it directly.